# Issue with page level SCSS import - NextJS

Tags: reactjs, webpack, sass, next.js

I am using NextJs in one of my projects. There are two sides to the project; one is the **"public pages side"** and the next one is the **"admin panel side"**. Just for illustrating, let's say **public.js** (inside the pages folder) renders the public page and **admin.js** renders the admin page and both of them do have different styles(themes).

- admin.scss is being imported in the adminpage.js file.

  ```
  import "../static/styles/admin.scss";      
  export default () => (<h1> Admin Page </h1>);
  ```
- public.scss is being imported in the publicpage.js file.

  ```
  import "../static/styles/public.scss";      
  export default () => (<h1> Public Page </h1>);
  ```

When I navigate to "HOST:PORT/admin" url, the styles for admin page are rendered correctly. After that, if I navigate to "HOST:PORT/public" url, this page will contain styles from "public.scss" as well as "admin.scss" (instead of importing just public.scss file) files which will cause some css properties overlapped. If I navigate back to "HOST:PORT/admin" url, the page will contain styles from "public.scss" as well as "admin.scss" files too.

One of the approaches I am using to fix this problem is by converting SCSS into CSS and injecting the CSS in link tag inside HEAD (next/head).

```
 /* For admin page */
 <Head>
       <link href="../static/styles/admin.css" rel="stylesheet" />
 </Head>

 /* For public page */
 <Head>
       <link href="../static/styles/public.css" rel="stylesheet" />
 </Head>
```

I want to use SCSS on page level without one the styles of one page messing up with the styles of another page.

Is there any good approach to do that?

My next.config.js is something like:

```
const withCss = require("@zeit/next-css");
const withSass = require('@zeit/next-sass');

if (typeof require !== "undefined") {
    require.extensions[".less"] = () => {};
    require.extensions[".css"] = file => {};
}

module.exports = withCss(withSass({
    publicRuntimeConfig: {...},
    webpack: function(config) {
        const originalEntry = config.entry;
        config.entry = async () => {
            const entries = await originalEntry();
            if (
                entries["main.js"] &&
                !entries["main.js"].includes("./polyfills.js")
            ) {
                entries["main.js"].unshift("./polyfills.js");
            }
            return entries;
        };

        config.module.rules.push({
            test: /\.(eot|woff|woff2|ttf|svg|png|jpg|gif)$/,
            use: {
                loader: "url-loader",
                options: {
                    limit: 100000,
                    name: "[name].[ext]"
                }
            }
        });
        return config;
    }
}));
```

Comment: What did you end up doing?

Comment: @TaylorA.Leach I end up using styled components.